# Red screen on my PC

Tags: laptop-repair

Whenever I play video games on my pc, after a little while, different parts of my screen start turning red, and it makes gaming on my pc almost intolerable. Any thoughts on what the problem could be? 
There has been a new development, I got a second screen and when the original red screened the other was fine. Why would this happen if it was an issue with the graphics card?

Comment: Provide graphics and other hardware details, or at least exact laptop model.

Comment: The model is HP Pavilion dv7 Notebook PC

Comment: HP is notorious for having bad cooling designs on their laptops. If it's under warranty contact support, otherwise clean any dust from the inside and try re-applying the thermal paste.

Comment: See [this page](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111020102132AAPwztj). Certainly looks like these are known for GPU failures.

Comment: When I see single-colour situations with a desktop monitor, I suspect display-connector issues.  Can heat cause ribbon-cable to shrink/retract from contacts on mainboard?

Comment: Any new answers for my edited question?

Comment: Possibly when the GPU is under load while playing games the connection to the LCD is failing (likely due to the heat), but the external video output is fine. In any case you need to get this looked at by a technician.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like an odd temperature-related problem.  If the laptop is under warranty, get it fixed.  If it isn't, experiment with some cooling of some sort.  What's the model?  Have you searched to see if others have a similar problem?